Delete rows in a sheet based on criteria defined on other sheet - VBA
I have an Excel file I've been working on and I'm trying to create a code with VBA to delete rows in a sheet that are defined in another sheet
On this table I have my data

On this one is specified which IDs are to delete on the font table based on a Yes/No condition

I want to generate a code that when the value is defined as "Y" search the ID from the remove table on the font table and delete the entire row on the font table.
The IDs on the remove table are listed from a filter formula so they won't always be the same quantity or order.
I am new to VBA, I tried to search online but didn't find anything that could work for me.

This is a code to start with. Checks only the size of the two ranges.
Sheet2 is the name of the need delete rows.
Sheet1 is the name of the data.
Sub DelSpecRows()

Dim delsh As Worksheet, datsh As Worksheet
Set delsh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set datsh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
lrowdel = delsh.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
lrowdat = datsh.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
If lrowdel <> lrowdat Then MsgBox ("Data size error")
For i = lrowdel To 1 Step -1  'reverse loop to avoid additional calculations of actual rows positions
  If delsh.Cells(i, 2) = "Y" Then
    datsh.Rows(i).Delete
  End If
Next i
End Sub


Version2
This code accepts the ID numbers to delete in any sequence.
Sub DelSpecRows()

Dim delsh As Worksheet, datsh As Worksheet
Set delsh = Worksheets("Munka2")
Set datsh = Worksheets("Munka1")
lrowdel = delsh.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
lrowdat = datsh.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
For i = 1 To lrowdel
  If delsh.Cells(i, 2) = "Y" Then
    datsh.Rows(Application.Match(delsh.Cells(i, 1), datsh.Range(datsh.Cells(1, 1), datsh.Cells(lrowdat, 1)), 0)).Delete
  End If
Next i
End Sub

SIDENOTE: In this case there is no need of marking Y or N of the ID's. It's enough to list the ID's in column A.
In this case delete lines If .....  and End If
SIDENOTE 2: If it is possible that ID is not listed on the datsh sheet add this line before the For loop
On Error Resume Next

This code assumes IDs are the same on both sheets (quantity and order).  While this is consistent with the sample data images provided, it is inconsistant with the description search the ID from the remove table on the font table and delete the entire row on the font table

What you comment is right. Therefore I mentioned code start with. I am waiting for the asker reaction of the answer. SO is not a free coding service, rather  to help on specific issues and other concrete problems at all.

The IDs on the remove table are listed from a filter formula so they won't always be the same quantity or order dependig on the criteria used to filter. So I need to find in wich row the ID specified as "Y" is located on the font table to remove that line

I added the new version to the answer. Would you please add the additional details to your question, for the future readers to clearly understand what is it about?

thanks Black cat! this new version worked.
Just added a UCase(delsh.Cells(i, 2)) = "Y" so it  got all values I needed to delete.
